# How to add data to the front with Redux-toolkit

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-toolkit

## Environment

react-native https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-39.0.3.tar.gz
redux-toolkit 1.4.0

## Code

there is code like that as Slice, im creating like chat app btw.
(in message page, scroll up and fetch old messages like normal chat app)

```
export const messageSlice = createSlice({
  name: key,
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      // fetch messages by ajax
      .addCase(fetchMessages.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        adapter.addMany(state, action.payload.messages);
      })
  },
});
```

now if there is data [4,5,6] and fetch messages data from server [1,2,3]. Result will be [4,5,6,1,2,3] by using "addMany()".

There is other way that data will be [1,2,3,4,5,6] by using method of redux toolkit?
or if you just know other way even if it is not method of redux toolkit, please write it down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, an entityAdapter does not care about order - and so everything is just added at the end. You can use a `sortComparer` though to keep the ids sorted.

```js
const itemsAdapter = createEntityAdapter({
  selectId: (item) => item.id,
  sortComparer: (a, b) => a.id-b.id,
})
```